# Как получить данные из elasticsearch (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

хочу подключиться к существующему эластику с помощью питона. elasticsearch.ping() работает, а вот с процедурой search пока не разобрался.

Пробую получить данные вот таким способом. Индекс посмотрел в эластике, но функция search возвращает None. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
import elasticsearch
import json


def search(es_object, index_name, search):
    res = es_object.search(index=index_name, body=search)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    es = connect_elasticsearch()
    if es is not None:
        search_object = {'query': {'match': {'message': '1'}}}
        a = search(es, 'index-2020.10.05', json.dumps(search_object))
        print(a)
```

Comment: В search return res

Comment: Если в функции нет инструкции return то она возвращает тип NoneType то есть фигвам